# Permanova with nested random effects?

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, biostatistics, permanova

I have an experimental design that looks like this:

Animals were reared from nine different source families and were placed in groups of 20 individuals into 18 rearing boxes (two boxes for each source family, assigned to two different treatment groups). From each of these 18 boxes I sampled one animal every three days, and performed chemical analyses (generating relative proportions of about 30 compounds). In total I have 108 samples (1 sample from each box at each of 6 time points, every time point therefore has 18 samples, 9 from each treatment).

I would like to run permanova to test for the effect of treatment and time (and their interaction) on the chemical profile. What would be the right way to do so? I thought that 'box' is nested within 'family', but if I try to specify such model like this:

```r
adonis2(Chemicals ~ Time*Treatment, strata=Family:Box)
```

I get errors:

```r
Error in Family:Boxx : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Family:Box :
  numerical expression has 108 elements: only the first used
2: In Family:Box :
  numerical expression has 108 elements: only the first used
3: In getPermuteMatrix(permutations, NROW(data), strata = strata) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
4: In getPermuteMatrix(permutations, NROW(data), strata = strata) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Adonis runs fine if I only use Box or Family as strata, but I guess that's not correct? I should control for the fact that animals were resampled from the same boxes over time, a repeated measure design, but also that there are 9 treatment pairs of samples for the 9 families at each time point.